# Null pointer exception while trying to modify a JFrame from another class?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

EDITED CODE:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.add(new StartPanel());
    frame.add(new InstructionsPanel());
    frame.add(new GamePanel());

    frame.getContentPane().getComponent(1).setVisible(false);
    frame.getContentPane().getComponent(2).setVisible(false);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

No matter what outside class I try to modify the frame from (any of the 3 panel classes above), I get a null pointer exception pointing to the line I am modifying something in the frame.

Comment: Why are you using static variables? First order of business: get rid of all static modifiers that you show above. Bring your code into the instance world.

Comment: You've changed the whole question which makes my current answer irrelevant. :( Not good.

Comment: Whoops, I apologize, I am new to this site :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Panel classes are created *before* the JFrame is created so the JFrame will be null in the Panel class constructors. But as per my comment, you should bring your code into the instance world by getting rid of those static modifiers. Your whole program design, to put it mildly, smells. Your main method should instead look something like:

```
private static void createAndShowGui() {
  // Model model = new MyModel();
  View view = new View();
  // Control control = new MyControl(model, view);

  JFrame frame = new JFrame("My GUI");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.getContentPane().add(view.getMainComponent());
  frame.pack();
  frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
  frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        createAndShowGui();
     }
  });
}
```

And View could look like:

```
public class View
  private StartPanel s = new StartPanel();
  private InstructionsPanel i = new InstructionsPanel();
  private GamePanel g = new GamePanel();
  private JPanel mainComponent = new JPanel();

  public View() {
    // create your GUI here
    // add components to mainComponent...
  }

  public JComponent getMainComponent() {
    return mainComponent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks. Now I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I am a bit new to the static modifier and all, and just had it there because the compiler told me to (yes I know, never go with the compiler before knowing what you are doing). How can I change my program so my variables are not required to be static?

Comment: @user2373733: No, the compiler didn't tell you to use the static modifier. Instead it told you that you can't use a static whatever in that context. The solution is not to use static to but to create instances and to call methods on instances not on classes. Again, the first thing you need to do is get rid of the static modifiers, and then when the compiler complains, fix the problem rather than make the variable static.

Comment: So you mean like frame.add(new GamePanel())?

Comment: @user2373733: it's hard to say without knowing the structure of your program, but possibly, or `frame.add(new GamePanel(frame));` where you pass the frame instance into GamePanel if need be.

Comment: Ahh disregard that, im stupid, I think I know how to fix this. Basically I am planning to make this class extend JFrame, then pretty much slap everything I have now into the constructor. Do you think that is a good idea?

Comment: @user2373733: I've created many GUI's, some for play, some for work, but I can count on one hand when I've needed to or wanted to have a class extend JFrame. I've extended JPanel many times, especially when I want to override the `getPreferredSize()` or `paintComponent(...)` methods, but JFrame, very rarely. I recommend against doing this unless absolutely necessary such as you need to override one of JFrame's methods. You're better off creating your JFrame and using it when needed.

Comment: Also, is it not ok to keep final variables static so I can access them in other classes, or should I create accessor methods for them?

Comment: @user2373733: none of your fields above should be static and you should not use static for this purpose. It is only used for fields and methods *of the class* or constants, period.

Comment: Oh ok, I am just having trouble figuring out how to fix this as I am new to some of this and just really confused right now. Any detailed advice on how I can make this work without the static modifiers? For example, without the static modifiers, how do I add the panels to the frame in the main method?

Comment: Also, how do I access one of my protected variables from another class in the package directly without the static modifier?

Comment: @user2373733: you pass in references where need be, as noted in my comment above, `frame.add(new GamePanel(frame));` so that now GamePanel has a reference to the object that frame refers to.

Comment: That is what I did at first, until I realized I had to toggle the visibility of the panels from other panel classes, and was not sure how to do so

Comment: Oh, I found some weird method to make everything work, so I guess I just needed to expand my view a bit. Thanks for the help

Comment: Not really weird, just something I did not expect to be possible I suppose. But back to the original problem: I changed my code to what I thought would work, but I still get the same null pointer exception. I will add the new edited code to the original post in a second